# Yii2 Allow action access only by POST request

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a yii2 controller, which meant to display statistics from database, for a specific user. There is a ajax request, performed to my controller action, but i want to restrict to allow only POST method for this action.

```
<?php
use yii\web\Response;
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\StatsModel;

class DataController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
            'only' => ['stats'],
             'formats' => [
                'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON 
              ],                
           ],
       ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionStats()
    {   
         //how can i restrict this action to only POST http method?
         return StatsModel::find()->all();
    }
}
```

I need to restrict `actionStats()` to HTTP Post method only.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd allow post only adding something like this to your behaviors:

```
'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'stats' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
```

And if you are accessing this action only through ajax, in your action you could add the following check

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
{
    //in case you want to return JSON formatted response
    Yii:$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
}
```

You can check this cookbook as well:

https://books.google.com.sv/books?id=CJrcDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=yii2+isajax&source=bl&ots=lRFEiPbN3K&sig=MFGo7VostVkxNZDbXGemXrm-qA8&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE9ZXSh7nbAhWPk1kKHW3wCeEQ6AEIYTAF#v=onepage&q=yii2%20isajax&f=false

Finally, you can just make the check for post in your action like this

```
public function actionStats()
{   
     if(Yii::$app->request->isPost())
     {
         //your logic here
         return StatsModel::find()->all();
     }
     else
         //throw an exception or return false
}
```

Comment: Just checked the link and it worked for me, i'm providing screenshot of link following https://prnt.sc/jqr3ww

Comment: I tried your answer, I received an error when used 'stats'  .

Comment: `'stats' => ['POST'],` makes reference to the name of the action the OP used. If you want to make your action accessible only through POST, the name of your action should be there instead of 'stats'. You can also check the API documentation: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter